# Order in tensor product

Tags: tensor-products

My Riemann geometry textbook tells me that the connection of a tensor product is defined by $$D(s_1\otimes s_2)=Ds_1\otimes s_2 +s_1\otimes Ds_2$$ but when it is calculating $t^{ij}_kdu^k\otimes \partial u_i\otimes D(\partial u_j)$
it gives 
$$t^{ij}_k\omega_j^l\otimes du^k\otimes \partial u_i\otimes \partial u_l$$
where it pulls the connection 1-form to the front, but I think this will be different from $$t^{ij}_kdu^k\otimes \partial u_i\otimes  \omega_j^l\otimes\partial u_l$$ which is the result given by the first formula. 
The order doesn’t matter here? Or am I missing something?

Comment: It is acting $D$ on a (1, 2) tensor $t$ and I just wrote the last term for sake of simplicity (on typing the formula)

Comment: Where do the $s_i$'s live?

Comment: @leibnewtz It’s a base for a general tensor space